# Интерактивная схема коммутации

Tags: сервер

Приветствую!

В серверной большая коммутационная панель.В процессе перекоммутации была заполнена рабочая схема на бумаге которая, естественно, про...терялась.Возник вопрос в создании этой же в электронном виде. Но так, как заполнить документ в екселе - это скучно и грустно - хотелось бы веб-мордочку, которая могла бы:

```
1. Отобразить N-патч-панелей 2. Отобразить N-свичей 3. Поиск порта: например вводишь 8-16, а он подсвечивает, сам порт 16 на 8 патч-панели, патч-корд и порт свича, куда он приходит (это баловство... но круто же) 4. Иметь возможность логирования (нужно, что бы была кнопка, которая открывала журнал, где сказано: Иван Факов чеиндж конекшн 8-16 ту свич 2-4) 5. Вы не поверите, но иметь возможность изменять конфиги из консоли :) 6. Возможность на схеме нажать на один порт, потом на другой, и что бы там нарисовался патч-корд, а в журнале написало текст из пункта 4
```

И в догонку: да, я понимаю что это глупости и баловство (и именно поэтому не сел за написание этой фигни сам). Но было бы очень классно, если кто-то встречался с уже написанными такими системами, и может ткнуть в них носом :)

Если хотя-бы 2 из 5 пунктов есть в системе, которую Вы знаете - можете ее предлагать. Особенно если она опенсорсовая и есть возможность допиливания.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я данную проблему решил так:взял мак адреса всех компов в сети, сопоставил их с номерами розеток(номер на розетке у пользователя совпадает с номером на патч-панели), после чего с коммутатора вытащил fdb таблицу с мак адресами и портами, на которых те светятся,и по макам которые у меня есть я сопоставил порт коммутатора с портом патчпанели.А уже все полученные данные можно вывести в html виде(jquery+php).я даже взял схему офиса и расставил все ПК по своим местам, ну дальше можно тварить всё что душа пожелает![alt text][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p44hf.png

Comment: Я еще подрабатывая в школьные годы в маленьких офисах отрисовывал в кореле похоже схему офиса, потом выкладывал страничкой в интранет, а дальше дорисовывал яваскриптом всплывающие подсказки :) потом научился к этим страничкам прикручивать пинг к машине, и отображение в случае пинг феилд. Дальше дело не зашло.А за Вашу идею - спасибо. Маки выдернул лансвипером. Пока не дают разрешения на раскопку свичей для выуживания из них таблиц. Работаю над этим.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите тут

[Comparison of network diagram software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_diagram_software)

Comment: Я тут ходил на длительный обед и раздумывал... В целом, все таки, это горожение дел над несуществующей проблемой.Хотя всё же было бы не плохо.За статью все равно спасибо. Большая часть приведенного в ней для рисования схемы сети point-to-point. Это стояло следующей задачей.

Answer (score 0):

Хм. Обидно, конечно, потерять важную бумагу...
Однако, разве Вы не нумеровали порты на панели и порты у юзера?
По номерам и восстановите.

Comment: Нумеровано, конечно.Но номер в люке у пользователя совпадает с номером на патч-панели. Дальше оттуда патч-кордом в свич (что естественно). Вот интересна именно последняя связка. Ибо при перекоммутации все патчкорды были заведены за усы стойки, что бы не висеть лапшой. Хрен теперь отследишь куда ведет тот или иной шнур.Не хочу бумагу. Или можно и бумагу, но электронный вариант должен остаться. Пока навожу в calc'e (openoffice) что удается выяснить.

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема-то? Нарисовать где, в какой комнате, и что у кого стоит? Я лично, это делал, и в виде веб-страниц. Правда, это было году в 1997-м, и большинство машин там были под никсами (IRIX, UnixWare, Nextstep, Linux, и классчесская System V), но ведь было!

Comment: Проблема не в рисовании, а в комутации. Человеку надо найти какой порт патч-панели в какой порт коммутатора воткнут, т.к. после перекомутации все патчкорды были утрамбованы в органайзер и продёрнуть каждый патчкорд не представляется возможным.

Comment: У меня для того кабель-тестер есть. Отключаешь всё нафиг, а потом проверяешь поочерёдно. У самого всё утрамбовант, что мама не горюй, однако работает!

Comment: проблема в том, что я не могу отрубить все нафиг :) слишком большими проблемами это сулит. Слишком большая инфраструктура. Часть машин выключена, часть ноутов на док станциях. То есть кабель должен быть обязательно... А если ноут заберут домой - пинга не будет. Машин всего около 200... + остальные сетевые устройства.ЗЫ. В 97-м я еще даже в школу не ходил ))

Comment: Коммутация??? Помню-помню, как в Амфеноле (на самом разъёме) при сборке провода перепутали! Я там чуть не свихнулся! Полсотни пар кабель-тестером проверял (на станции два Амфенола было)!!!

Comment: А вообще-то и не надо отключать всех. надо сперва просто новый кабель пробросить, и подкдючать уже туда, где старый не работал. Будешь смеяться, но я, поочерёдно отключая и подключая, так, почти незаметно, и вывел свою контору на новый роутер, и новую офисную АТС! Некоторые сотрудники и не заметили даже.